# Configure keybindings for google chrome

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, key-bindings

I use Google Chrome on Mac OS and I would like to know how I can configure a specific keybinding that exists in Safari.
For example, when searching something in Google, I can press the <kbd>TAB</kbd>  key and change between the results. After, if I use the <kbd>⌘</kbd>+ <kbd>enter</kbd> keybinding, the current link is open in another tab. I want to be able to make the same thing on Chrome. Anyone know a good way to make that? 
Thanks.

Comment: It has been filed in a bug here: https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=27946 But you still could use the chrome extension here for the same purpose: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/shortcut-manager/mgjjeipcdnnjhgodgjpfkffcejoljijf/related